# Python remove elements from unknown list with a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are similar questions to this but not quite what im looking for.

Having created a list with all files from a specific path im looking to filter out anything that does not contain a specific sequence in a string.

```
def filter():
    someFiles = os.listdir(somePath)
    listSize = len(someFiles)

    for i in range(0, listSize):
        if (".py" not in someFiles):
            someFiles.remove(i)
            print("{0}".format(someFiles))
```

Im aware i shouldn't be modifying the size of a list through a loop but i left it just to roughly give an idea of what i'm trying to accomplish

I did not make it clear, the issue that im facing is that i'm not sure what approach i should be taking when trying to remove every element that does not contain ".py". What I wrote above is more of a rough draft.

Comment: what problem did you face...

Comment: You could create a new list based on the old one:

`files = [f for f in someFiles if ".py" not in f]`

Comment: @pschill Using this approach requires `if ".py" in f` (note that OP **removes** the files that don't have `'.py'` in them).

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes you are right. I misread that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, listSize):
    if (".py" not in someFiles):
        someFiles.remove(i)
```

Note that you are trying to remove `i` from the list. `i` will be an index of an element in the list (`0`, `1`, etc) and not an actual element. This will raise an error.

Simply use list comprehension to get only the files you *do* need:

```
required_files = [f for f in someFiles if '.py' in f]
```

You could also use `filter` but it will require a lambda (and also note it will return a `filter` object and not a `list`):

```
required_files = list(filter(lambda x: '.py' in x, someFiles))
```

Comment: Right, my logic was off, this is what i was trying to do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to use for loop to iterate over a list in Python. Simpler version of what you've done would be

```
list2 = []
for filename in list1:
    if (".py" in filename):
        list2.append(filename)
```

but filtering a list (or more generally, an iterator) is so common, that there is Python builtin function called, unsurprisingly, `filter`:

```
list2 = list(filter(lambda i: ".py" in i, list1))
```

(this would work at least in Python3)

Comment: Yeah i dont know why i was trying to remove, this  works perfect. Thank you